# How not to let Windows 10 (version 1709) mangle my wireless network priorities?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

## TL;DR

Windows 10 automatically reorders the priority of saved wired networks when I try to connect on one of those manually. How can I keep it from doing so? (How can I enforce priority set by **me**, not Windows?)

---

Suppose I have these wireless networks saved on my Win 10:

- Network Z
- Network X
- Network Y
- ...

Among these, *Y* and *Z* co-exists in a place, and I usually prefer *Y* over *Z* because *Y* gives me a better signal strength than *Z*. So, I have set the order (priorities) of these networks manually via `netsh wlan`'s `set profileorder` command like this:

- Network *Y* (priority=1)
- Network *Z* (priority=2)
- Network *X* (priority=3)
- ...

However, sometimes I do need to connect to *Z*. However when I connect to *Z* manually, Windows immediately prioritize it over *Y*, ruining the priority list set by me. It will look like this now:

- Network *Z* (priority=1, **modified by Windows**)
- Network *Y* (priority=2, **modified by Windows**)
- Network *X* (priority=3)
- ...

I didn't ask for this *automatic prioritizing* nor I like it. How can I stop Windows' ruthless mangling on my network priority list?

Comment: Try and see if you have any Intel wireless management software or similar. I've had issues where a PC keeps defaulting back to a network I don't want it to and it turned out no matter how many times I set it in network & sharing, the only thing that kept it stable was checking in the Intel software.

Comment: @CiaranMcKenzie I guess mine is not like the case you mentioned; I don't have any Intel software installed except ME, Graphics, RST, and Serial IO.